# Adding attribute to XML Node always fail

Tags: c#, xml

I always get exception below when try to add attribute, why it's not working?

> The prefix '' cannot be redefined from '' to 'http://ws.plimus.com'
>   within the same start element tag.

Code

```
var docXml = new XElement("param-encryption", 
    new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://ws.plimus.com"),
    new XElement("parameters"));

var s = docXml.ToString();
```

I want to get result like

```
<param-encryption xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
  <parameters>


  </parameters>
</param-encryption>
```

Comment: Is this a root element?

Comment: @Amit Yes, this is root element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simplest approach is to let LINQ to XML do this automatically by specifying the namespace in the element name:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://ws.plimus.com";
var docXml = new XElement(ns + "param-encryption", new XElement(ns + "parameters"));
```

Result of `docXml.ToString()`:

```
<param-encryption xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
  <parameters />
</param-encryption>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
XNamespace aw = "http://ws.plimus.com";
XElement root = new XElement("param-encryption",
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "aw", "http://ws.plimus.com"),
    new XElement("Child", "child content")
);
Console.WriteLine(root);
```

(EDIT):- 
use this if you dont want namespace alias

```
XNamespace aw = "http://ws.plimus.com";
    XElement root = new XElement(aw + "param-encryption",
        new XAttribute("xmlns",  "http://ws.plimus.com"),
        new XElement( aw  + "Child", "child content")
    );
```

Comment: That won't create the XML that OP described.